# how to take input from user on slack to proceed further?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

Im working on chatbot where bot ask users name and then bot replies with Greeting + name. This works when I use this on terminal with input() but not able to figure out how to accept input from slack and use that input.

```
def start(request, channel):
    response = ('\n\nHello!')
    send_response(response, channel)
    name = ('Please tell me your name.\n')
    send_response(name, channel)    
    name = request
    greet = "Hello" + name
    send_response(greet, channel)

def send_response(response,channel):
    slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=response, as_user=True)

def parse_slack_output(slack_rtm_output):
    output_list = slack_rtm_output
    if output_list and len(output_list) > 0:
        for output in output_list:
            if output and 'text' in output and AT_BOT in output['text']:
                # return text after the @ mention, whitespace removed
                return output['text'].split(AT_BOT)[1].strip(), \
                    output['channel']
    return None, None

if __name__ == "__main__":

    READ_WEBSOCKET_DELAY = 1 # 1 second delay between reading from firehose
    if slack_client.rtm_connect():
        print ("connected and running!")
        while True:
            request, channel = parse_slack_output(slack_client.rtm_read())
            if request and channel:
                start(request, channel)
            time.sleep(READ_WEBSOCKET_DELAY)
    else:
        print("Connection failed. Invalid Slack token or bot ID?")
```

Answer (score 1):

As per slack doc, dialog.open() method is the way to achieve your requirement.
https://api.slack.com/dialogs.

EDIT:
And RASA NLU-CORE gives more option for conversational based ChatBots. http://rasa.com/docs/core/quickstart/

Slot Filling is what you need to look into to store the name or any other values and use it further in the conversation.

Comment: This will technically work, but a chat-based conversation would be more user friendly for the use case in my opinion.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken , I have updated the answer based On your comment :)